# Question closed as opinion-based, suggestion on where to ask it?

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions

This question of mine was closed as opinion-based:

[I have an iPhone XS, should I update to iOS 15.2?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/433653/272604)

I understand the reason for closing my question. I also received an helpful comment (thanks). Could you please suggest me some other Internet place where I could ask this question? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe Macrumors?

Comment: AskDifferent is a *support* site, you need to find a *discussion* site MacRumors is such a place as is Reddit. There are many. While some discussion sneaks in from time to time on AD, we really try and keep it to a minimum and isolated to brief comments on valid questions.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy thanks!

Comment: @SteveChambers thanks! Yes, I understand now that my question is not appropriate.  I asked it because I thought it could be answered objectively (like, iOS 15.2 is objectively better for iPhone XS or not), but I was wrong. I may ask on Reddit or Macrumors...but I'm starting to think I should just upgrade.